# Wiring spring beans through custom reporting context in grails

Tags: spring, grails, jasper-reports, context.xml

I am using Jasper Reports for my Grails based web application and I have a ReportingContext.xml which has beans for each report like report id/name mapping with the report template (jrxml). I need to know the basic steps to configure and setup the context xmls and how to load them into my reportscontroller at application startup.

The old application was in java/j2ee  which used this reporting xml. We have to develop a similar system on grails.

Most of the context contains the jrxml to report name mapping but I am not able to understand some of the beans in the context.

Here is the sample content of the reporting context.xml , for 1 report

```
 <beans> 
            <!-- ========================= REPORTING SERVICE WRAPPER ========================= -->
             <bean parent="baseTransactionProxy" name="myReportingService"> 
             <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.pack.my.reporting.service.myReportingService"/> 
             <property name="transactionAttributes">
                 <property name="target"> 
             <bean parent="baseServiceSupport" class="com.pack.my.reporting.service.impl.myReportingServiceImpl"> 
             <property name="reportManager" ref="reportManager"/> 
             <property name="mySecurityService" ref="mySecurityService"/> 
             <property name="businessUnitService" ref="businessUnitService"/> 
             </bean> 
             </property> 
             </bean> 
             <bean class="com.pack.my.reporting.manager.impl.ReportManagerImpl" id="reportManager"> 
             <property name="reportRenderers"> 
             <map> 
             <entry key="JasperPrint">
                 <entry key="siemJasperPrint">
             </map>
             </property>
             <property name="reportDefinitionDao" ref="reportDefinitionDao"/> 
             <property name="reportDao" ref="reportDao"/> 
             <property name="sequenceGeneratorService" ref="sequenceGeneratorService"/> 
             <property name="reportLocation" value="file:${my_HOME}/reports"/> 
             <property name="reportDefinitions">
                 <map> 
                 <entry key="businessUnitRoles"> 
                 <ref local="businessUnitRoles"/> 
                 </entry>
                 <entry key="businessUnitRoleUsers"> 
                 <ref local="businessUnitRoleUsers"/> 
                 </entry>
                 </map>
             </property>
             <property name="parameterPromptCodeMap">
                 <bean class="org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap"> 
                 <constructor-arg> 
                 <map> 
                 <entry value="1" key="businessUnit"/> 
                 <entry value="1" key="businessUnitKey"/> 
                 <entry value="2" key="globaluser"/> 
                 <entry value="2" key="USERID"/> 
                 <entry value="2" key="USER_ID"/> 
                 <entry value="2" key="GLOBALUSERKEY"/> 
                 <entry value="3" key="identityCertification"/> 
                 <entry value="3" key="CERTIFICATIONID"/> 
                 <entry value="3" key="CERTIFICATION_ID"/> 
                 <entry value="4" key="startDate"/> 
                 </map> 
                 </constructor-arg> 
                 </bean> 
                 </property>
             </bean> 
            <!--- Report Groups Business Unit reports Group 1 Users reports -->
             <bean class="com.pack.my.reporting.domain.ReportDefinition" id="businessUnitRoles">
                 <property name="reportName" value="Business Unit Roles Report"/> 
                 <property name="reportFiles"> 
                 <map> 
                 <entry value="BusinessUnitRoles.jrxml" key="JasperPrint"/> 
                 </map> 
                 </property> 
                 <property name="promptForBusinessUnit" value="true"/> 
                 <property name="reportGroup" value="1"/> 
                 <property name="displayName" value="report.businessUnitRoles.name"/>
             <bean class="com.pack.my.reporting.domain.ReportDefinition" id="businessUnitUsers">

             </bean>
            </beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add dependencies to grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
2. Copy the above file to /grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml
3. Read [Grails and Spring - Reference Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html)

The resources.xml is not built by default anymore, as only resources.groovy exists in the spring dir.  Just copy your spring context file to resources.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I have resources.groovy which is empty right now, I guess I can load up the xml there or just have a resources.xml there?..Thanks, Priyank